# Typing filepath as a string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm writing the following code to read in a file from the filepath given (Using VS2010 & C#):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string temp;
        string path = "C:\Windows\Temp\fmfozdom.5hn.rdl";
        using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(stream);
            temp = r.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(temp);
    }
```

The compiler is complaining about the following line:

```
string path = "C:\Windows\Temp\fmfozdom.5hn.rdl";
```

It gives the message: Unrecognised escape sequence at **\W** and **\T**

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx):

```
string path = @"C:\Windows\Temp\fmfozdom.5hn.rdl";
```

Either that, or escape the `\` character:

```
string path = "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\fmfozdom.5hn.rdl";
```

The problem with your current code is that the `\` is the escape sequence in the string and `\W`, `\T` are unknown escapes.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to:

```
string path = "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\fmfozdom.5hn.rdl";
```

The reason is that it's interpreting the 'W' and 'T' as escape characters since you only used one '\'.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a forward slash in windows for this.  This would remove the need for escaping the backslash.